# iCloud Drive Ubiquity Container Folder not showing

Tags: ios, info.plist, icloud-drive, icloud-documents, ubiquitycontainer

I am trying to help users synchronise files created by some other app. So my idea was to have an iCloud Drive folder (like iWork/iLife apps), where the user can save the files from the other app into my app's iCloud Drive folder where I can access the files...

Now, afaik I need to use Ubiquity Containers to do so and so I tried out [this example](https://github.com/anas-p/Save-To-iCloud-Drive/). I was able to get files into iCloud, meaning there is a `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~appId~MyApp/Documents` folder, I see in Terminal, however there is no folder either in Finder or Files... My code (including Info.plist & .entitlements) is basically the same as the example...

I tried:

- Delete & reinstalling
- restart iOS-device
- turn iCloud Drive off & an again
- increase Build Nr.

There are 2 things that keep me thinking:

1. Is it because I'm in a dev environment and folders only show in prod?
2. I don't have an app icon. Do I need an icon to have an iCloud Drive folder?

If you have any idea feel free to share... Thank you :)